# How to use home component data in other component?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Below is my code, how to use (this.categoryType) in other component

```
getCategoryDetails(){
return this.http.get('ip/ramu/api/api/…')
.map((res:Response) => res.json());
}
```

Above code I am using in webservice.ts

```
ngOnInit() { this.wsp.getCategoryDetails().subscribe(data => {
this.categoryType = data; });
}
```

Above code I have used in home.ts, but I want use this response in other component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a service to save the category. And then you can use the same service to get the categoryType whenever you want it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class AppMessageQueuService {

    categoryType: string;
    constructor() {

    }
    saveCateogry(cat:any){
        this.categoryType= cat;
    }
    retrieveCategory(){
        return this.categoryType;
    }

}
```

Then you can inject this Service into both the components and save it from the first component like,

```
this.appMsgService.saveCateogry(yourcategory);
```

then retrieve in the second component as,

```
this.appMsgService.retrieveCategory();
```