# Sharing data across components

Tags: angular

I am developing an Angular4 app, my main issue is that I've different components inside an app, for example

```
<app-layout>
 <app-component-1></app-component-1>
 <app-component-2></app-component-2>
</app-layout>
```

Now my question is the next one, if I click in some element from component-1 app-layout should be notified and component-2 too, and when I click on component-2, app-layout and component-1 should be notified also.

Imagine the scenario to open sidebars and select categories and sub-categories.

Comment: Please use these links [**1.ngrx-store**](https://github.com/aravindfz/ngrx-store-demo)(redux for angular) [**2. shared services**](https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/)

Comment: @Aravind if the project is small there is no need of redux. Believe me, my team find it the hard way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984240/how-to-use-home-component-data-in-other-component/44984302#44984302

Comment: you need to educate your team. Let me know I will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options for this:

1) You can use @Input and @Output properties to communicate between the parent (app-layout) and the children (component-1 and component-2). Using this technique the children would each have to communicate with the parent who would then pass along any info to the other children.

I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/passing-data-to-and-raising-an-event-from-a-nested-component/

2) You can use a service. A service in Angular is a singleton, meaning it is managed as a single instance. So if each of the components access the service, they will access the same shared data.

I have an example of using a service for communication here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

Comment: Thanks, I think that I solved this problem using input/output and inside the layout using viewChild decorator.

For now it works properly, but when it gets more complicated I think that I am going over a service.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is service + rxjs.

Here is one very good article how to do it.

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject